# How do I create a GtkImage from a Cairo surface?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to be able to make a GtkImage from a Cairo surface (without writing a temp file).

I currently write the surface as PNG to a char array which I then feed to a PixbufLoader to get a Pixbuf which I use to create the GtkImage:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char *pos;
    unsigned char *end;
} closure_t;

static cairo_status_t
png_to_array (void *closure, const unsigned char *data, unsigned int length)
{
    closure_t *cl = (closure_t *) closure;

    if ((cl->pos + length) > (cl->end))
        return CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR;

    memcpy (cl->pos, data, length);
    cl->pos += length;

    return CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


// later in the code
cairo_surface_t *surface = ...

...

// how would i determine the right size?
unsigned char arr[...];
closure_t cl;
GtkWidget *image;
GdkPixbufLoader *pbloader;
GdkPixbuf *pb;

// copy surface png to arr
cl.pos = arr;
cl.end = arr + sizeof(arr);
cairo_surface_write_to_png_stream (surface,
                    (cairo_write_func_t) png_to_array,
                    &cl);

...
// write to pixbufloader, get pixbuf, create image
pbloader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new();
gdk_pixbuf_loader_write(pbloader, arr, sizeof(arr), NULL);
gdk_pixbuf_loader_close(pbloader, NULL);

pb = gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_pixbuf(pbloader);

image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pb);
```

1. This seems rather cumbersome - isn't there an easier way to do this?
2. How would I determine the size of the array in my example?

Answer (score 1):

One function will save you a lot of effort here.  Look up gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface.  It gets a Pixbuf from a cairo_surface_t.  Of coarse, realising as he writes it, that is only available if you use Gdk-3.0, which also means using Gtk+-3.0.

Of coarse if you want to use Gtk+-2.0 then you can create a pixmap, get a cairo_t from it then copy your other cairo_surface_t to it by

```
cairo_set_source_surface (cr, surface, x0, y0);
cairo_rectangle (cr, x0 + x, y0 + y, width, height);
cairo_fill (cr);
```

A example of how to create a pixmap is below, I'll let you fill in the rest.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>


int main(gint argc, gchar *argv[])
{
    GdkPixmap *pixmap;
    GtkWidget *image;
    GtkWidget *window;
    cairo_t *cr;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    pixmap = gdk_pixmap_new(window->window, 100, 100, -1);
    cr = gdk_cairo_create(pixmap);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);    
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 10, 10, 80, 80);
    cairo_fill(cr);
    cairo_destroy(cr);

    cr = NULL;



    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixmap(pixmap, NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);


    gtk_widget_show(image);



    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, I'm not sure how to determine the size of the array but I'm sure how long should be the size of the array since what your png_to_array callback will be called several times the size of your array should be the sum of all lengths

I'm using the stride to determine the size of array but at the end the total_lenght will determine the size of the png

```
int total_lenght = 0;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char *pos;
    unsigned char *end;
} closure_t;

static cairo_status_t
png_to_array (void *closure, const unsigned char *data, unsigned int length)
{
    closure_t *cl = (closure_t *) closure;

    if ((cl->pos + length) > (cl->end))
        return CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR;

    memcpy (cl->pos, data, length);
    cl->pos += length;

    total_lenght += lenght;

    return CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


// later in the code
cairo_surface_t *surface = ...

...

int stride = cairo_image_surface_get_stride(surface);

unsigned char *arr = (unsigned char *) malloc(stride);
closure_t cl;
GtkWidget *image;
GdkPixbufLoader *pbloader;
GdkPixbuf *pb;

// copy surface png to arr
cl.pos = arr;
cl.end = arr + stride;
cairo_surface_write_to_png_stream (surface,
                    (cairo_write_func_t) png_to_array,
                    &cl);

...
// write to pixbufloader, get pixbuf, create image
pbloader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new();
gdk_pixbuf_loader_write(pbloader, arr, total_lenght), NULL);
gdk_pixbuf_loader_close(pbloader, NULL);

pb = gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_pixbuf(pbloader);

image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gtk3 then you can use the function [new_from_surface](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/ctor.Image.new_from_surface.html).

Just to show how you can achieve what you were trying to do, basically you were in the right path, with dynamic allocation using **realloc**:

```c
typedef struct
{
    size_t length;
    unsigned char *data;
} png_buffer;

static cairo_status_t
png_to_buffer (void *closure, const unsigned char *data, unsigned int length)
{
    png_buffer *buff = (png_buffer *)closure;
    buff->data = (unsigned char *)realloc(buff->data, sizeof(unsigned char) * (buff->length + length)); // We reallocate the buffer
    memcpy( // Copy the data to the buffer considering the offset
        &(buff->data[buff->length]), // This is the same as buff->data + buff->length
        data,
        sizeof(unsigned char) * length
    );
    buff->length += length;
    return CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


// later in the code
cairo_surface_t *surface = ...

...
png_buffer png_data = {
    .length = 0,
    .data = NULL // realloc will allocate the memory
};
GtkWidget *image;
GdkPixbufLoader *pbloader;
GdkPixbuf *pb;

// copy surface to png_buffer
cairo_surface_write_to_png_stream (surface,
                    (cairo_write_func_t) png_to_buffer,
                    (void *)&png_data);

...
// write to pixbufloader, get pixbuf, create image
pbloader = gdk_pixbuf_loader_new();
gdk_pixbuf_loader_write(pbloader, (guchar *)png_data.data, (gsize)png_data.length, NULL);
gdk_pixbuf_loader_close(pbloader, NULL);

pb = gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_pixbuf(pbloader);

image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pb);
```